# JQuery hover related information for an image from database based on ID

Tags: php, jquery

I have a 'post' row in my database where all the posted posts are stored.
Each post includes an id, image, title, description. I retrieve it to the main page using a while loop and I want to create a hover effect on each image that will display its corresponding information (the title and the description) based on its id.

I tried a few things with jquery but didn't seem to go anywhere.

**Basic version of the database row displayed on html:**

```
<img src="http://www.extremetech.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/VWXL1-1024-640x426.jpg" class="post" id="1">
<div class="ad_fade" id="fade1"></div>    

<img src="http://www.hdwallpaperscool.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/peter-pan-cars-sports-car-hd-wallppers-cool-desktop-images.jpg" class="post" id="2">
<div class="ad_fade" id="fade2"></div>         

<img src="http://www.hdwallpapers.in/walls/corvette_mallett_concept_car-HD.jpg" class="post" id="3">
<div class="ad_fade" id="fade3"></div>
```

in the php code I have each img tag have an id setup like so: id="'.$id.'" where $id is a unique id returned from the database

**the styling:**

```
.post{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
}
.ad_fade{
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    margin:-105px 0 0;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/g45db/

I am trying to create a similar effect as seen on: http://dribbble.com/
It has to hover the related info for that specific image in a dynamic way.

All help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like,

```
$(function(){
    $('img.post').hover(function(){
        $(this).next('div').show().html(this.src);
         // you can use ajax to get data from database
    });
});
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/g45db/2/)

**Updated** try to use `mouseleave` on `div.ad_fade` like

```
$(function () {
    $('img.post').hover(function () {
        $(this).next('div').show().html($(this).data('title')); // using title here
        // you can use ajax to get data from database
    });
    $('div.ad_fade').on('mouseleave',function(){ // mouse leave for fadeout div
        $(this).fadeOut(1000).html('');
    });
});
```

[Updated Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/g45db/5/)

Comment: how can i do the fade out? i got everything else going http://jsfiddle.net/g45db/4/

Comment: that's perfect. Is there any way to position the ad_fade div on top without the -105px margin?

Comment: Yes remove `margin` and use `top:0` See http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/g45db/6/

Answer (score 0):

You either need container to hold title and description on hover of img, create as two separate divs

Try to store information in img tag as data-title and data-description and then apply onmouse over function of jquery to show hover effects

```
$('img').onmouseover(function(){
var $this = $(this);
var title = $this.data('title');
// try to append title and description in previously created divs
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to display title and description, use title attribute of img tag like below

```
<img src="http://www.extremetech.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/VWXL1-1024-640x426.jpg" class="post" id="1" title="Title and Description">
```

And if you want to use jquery then use below code. First populate title and description in each  for respective image.

```
<img src="http://www.extremetech.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/VWXL1-1024-640x426.jpg" class="post" id="1">
<div class="ad_fade" id="fade1">Title and Description details</div> 

  $('img').mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).next('.ad_fade').show();
  });

  $('.ad_fade').mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).hide();
  });
```

Comment: [closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest) used to traverse an element for its ancestors and OP has element after the image, so closest will not work here. Try [next()](http://api.jquery.com/next)

Comment: closest is also work in this case as i tried but yes you are right that it should be next(). Let me update my answer. Thanks @Rohan Kumar

Comment: @RohanKumar, you are right it is not working with closest().  please find working demo at http://jsfiddle.net/g45db/18/